# Unable to search by word "company"

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Both the below questions are related to same `index`

1) I am using Elastic search. My text contains word "companies"

> For example: John has worked with companies like Bharat Electronics
>   and Gillette in senior management positions, wherein he has  set up
>   new units, managed talent acquisition, systems, processes and laying
>   out SOP for Human Resources

When I search using following query, I don't find any result however it should have returned data:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": 
            { 
                "fields.bio": "company"

            }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get zero records however it should have found above record.

2) While creating an index I used `english stop words` but it still returns records bases on words like `an`. 
The code I used to create an index:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "my_stop": {
                    "type":       "stop",
                    "stopwords":  "_english_"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, it should not return any record even though the text contain `an` word But in reality it is returning records if it finds `an` word in records.

The index mapping is as follows:

```
{
    "experts": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "categories": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "expertise": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "fields": {
                    "properties": {
                        "annual_income": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "avg_rating": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "bio": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "calls": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "current_company": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "current_country_id": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "current_position": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "email": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "id": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "linkedin_url": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "mobileno": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "profile_photo_url": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "review_count": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "total_experience": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "username": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "users": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "functions": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "industries": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "qualifications": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Could you share index mapping?

Comment: @Rob Added mapping just now in the question